# Is it true that Lord Buddha was born in Sri Lanka?

Tags: the-buddha, ethics, history

I've heard there's a rumor saying that lord Buddha was born in Sri Lanka and ancient "Dambadiwa" is not India but Sri Lanka. There's a "sal" tree in Sri Lanka which matches to the exact tree that we believe which was there in the birth of baby prince  "siddhartha" . I dunno whether they're true or not I just wanna know whether there's a truth behind it, whether what we believe so far is just a lie?! (Ps not Buddhism but the life story of Lord Buddha)

Comment: Three of the answers here (one of which is from a high-rep user, and another from a moderator) just say "I _personally_ think it's not true", without presenting any evidence. What is the threshold for evidence on this website? Is it not the same as on the rest of Stack Exchange?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The policies here are unlike those of many other SE sites -- see [FAQ index (summary of site policies)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/254). References are welcome but are not required (see [What about providing sources?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/254)). Unreferenced answers could be questioned or challenged politely, using a comment, or you can use a comment to suggest an improvement; but e.g. these answers are presenting statements as personal opinions. If you have further questions like this, please ask on Meta.

Comment: Where he was born is of no importance whatsoever. The fact that he was born, had all these amazing insights and was a fantastic teacher is what is important. Being fixated on historical facts like this blinds you to the message. Worshipping or venerating a place is not what Buddhism is about. Following the path Buddha taught is. Being fixated on places is being fixated and attached to this world, which is not what Buddha taught. Sure, treat them with respect, but you should do that to everywhere and everything anyway regardless of if Siddhartha was maybe born there or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prince Siddhartha was raised, according to Buddhist texts, in ***Kapilawastu*** (I will not present sources for this as I think this would be undisputed).

The modern name for Kapilawastu is unknown: I will quote a [note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha#cite_note-birthplace-3) from Wikipedia page for [Gautama Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha).

> The exact location of ancient Kapilavastu is unknown. It may have been either Piprahwa in Uttar Pradesh, northern India, or Tilaurakot, present-day Nepal. The two cities are located only fifteen miles from each other.

The Buddha's birthplace is said to be Lumbini, and it should not be any farther from Kapilawasthu than few days of travel by horse-carriage. So the birthplace must still be in the India or Nepal, even if one discounts the pillar erected by Emperor Ashoka at [Lumbini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbini). (The place previously known as *Rummindei* was [renamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbini#Rediscovery) to Lumbini when the Ashokan pillar was found in 1896.)

The note quoted above is well cited, and it is evident that although the exact birthplace is unknown, it has been at least reduced to a very small area, thousands of Kilometers from Sri Lanka.

The disputes for birthplaces of religious figures are not uncommon in present day. For example, even though there is overwhelming evidence suggesting that Jesus was born somewhere in Middle East, there are Christian groups who believe that he was born in some place in United States, for example, Alabama.

Answer (score 8):

Lumbini, Nepal has been recognized as the birthplace of Siddhartha Gautama since a stone pillar was placed at the site by the emperor Ashoka circa 245 BCE.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbini

Answer (score 6):

I personally believe that Buddha was born in [Lumbini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbini) in Nepal through in recent times there are a few small groups in Sri Lanka saying otherwise. I personally would be careful about these movements and groups.

Answer (score 4):

There's no truth in it. But people usually like to hear new things. So any new idea presented with some make-belief evidence can get a following.

Answer (score 3):

I echo what Suminda and Sankha has already mentioned.

Be cautious about what you hear or read.

I doubt that the Buddha was born in Sri Lanka. Personally, I don't believe it to be true.

As Sankha mentioned - it might be a tactic to gain followers.

Answer (score 3):

Buddha was born at Lumbini, Nepal.That is also close on india border . So nowadays , india also claim birthplace of buddha was India.But , there is no chance that buddha birthplace is Srilanka.