# Was Anuruddha, one of the ten Great Disciples of the Buddha, born in Sri Lanka?

Tags: pali-canon, early-buddhism

When I was searching for the translated name from Chinese 阿那律 to Sanskrit while attempting a *comment* on [one post](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/21951/10304), I entered 阿那律 or Anuruddha to Google it came up with the list and the usual short brief at the right corner of the screen, to my amusement the brief said:

> Anuruddha
>
> **Born: Sri Lanka**

[image]

Though I open the brief the Wikipedia full page is `Born: Kapilavastu, India`

Is there a [movement to relocate Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/21485/10304) (not just relocate, but part of the grand scheme to **invent** in the sense of *re-invent* Buddha's teachings) to be originated from Sri Lanka since the Sri Lankan Pali Canon is splendidly adored as the only authentic plus the most early Buddhism's teaching? - As the first step. Now here comes the next step to relocate Buddha gradually first by *migrating* `:D !!` one of his ten major disciples? I'm diligently waiting to be enlightened in this context.

Comment: thank you @ChrisW. but you edited my original question to render this question totally like an idiot making a silly question. i can do nothing but only to remove it.

Comment: I restored your original question.

Comment: thank you @ChrisW we should respect all Buddhist schools. also as Buddhists we should uphold the correct teachings, neither should let it being corrupted by **insider** nor **outsider**. thus it's a valid question to ask in this manner. anyone concerned should be aware of if there is such an attempt or trend.

Answer (score 2):

Anuruddha-mahāsāmi (thai:anuruddhācāriya) was one of ancient saṅgarāja in sri lanka. He author abhidhammatthasaṅgaha, that is popular summary of  abhidhamma-pitaka.

Comment: thank you for enlightening me on this piece of knowledge of the abhidhamma-pitaka. but in term of prominence if i simply type Anuruddha it should come up with the info of Anuruddha-mahasami.

Comment: It is bug of google.

Comment: *if i simply type Anuruddha it **should** come up with the info of Anuruddha-mahasami.* - typo: it **shouldn't**

Comment: By over 10 years experience with pali canon, I completely say that no pali canon wrote "anuruddha-aggasavaka born in sri lanka". Just google wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

I've no previous experience with how Google creates this kind of summary.

I'm not sure I understand where Google got that data from, to put in its summary -- "Sri Lanka" isn't given in any version of [the history of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Anuruddha&action=history).

There are [modern Anuruddhas born in Sri Lanka](https://www.google.com/search?q=Anuruddha+born+Sri+Lanka) (e.g. a cricketer) but that (mixing different people with the same name) seems like an unlikely or silly mistake for Google to make.

The image (of a statue) in the Google summary does comes from a different web site (not Wikipedia) though, so maybe Google does aggregate data from different sites somehow.

Based on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Persondata) I wonder if it's possible that Google prefers to scrape its data from Wikidata instead of from Wikipedia -- the [Wikidata entry for Anuruddha](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3306373) doesn't include a birth place (it was in the Wikipedia article but not in the Persondata template when [the Persondata template was migrated to Wikidata](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Anuruddha&type=revision&diff=710782271&oldid=708599211)) so perhaps Google is aggregating from several sites, getting its information mixed up, or confusing it with a modern Anaruddha?

If you want to report a correction to Google's summary, perhaps you could try editing the Wikidata entry, and/or pressing the Feedback link on the Google summary.

Comment: it's the same result with **born: Sri Lanka** when I entered 阿那律. i can't see there would be a person in the same name as 阿那律 in the manner your explaint above, @ChrisW.

Comment: I too see "born: Sri Lanka" in the Google summary, same as shown in the image you posted. What I don't know is where Google gets that data from. I know that people sometimes make (disputed) edits to Wikipedia, and so I thought that maybe Google was displaying someone's old Wikipedia edit ... but in the history of the Wikipedia article I see no version with that data. I cannot confirm nor deny your hypothesis, that a human created that data intentionally.

Comment: thx for the knowledge of the technical part about how Google/Wikipedia renders data etc.